# Creating report in asp.net by accessing server side code and not a database

Tags: asp.net, reporting

I'm trying to create a report in asp.net by using data from a form that a user fills up.

I know that I can do this in windows form mode by creating a class and using that as a data source for a .rdlc file.

However, in the case of ASP.Net I can't seem to find a similar approach.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: It's exactly the same for ASP.NET reporting - fill an object (e.g. Datatable) with your form data and add it to report's Datasource collection

Comment: I don't think it is. In windows form you can press (Shift+Alt+D) to bring data sources pane. Then you can add a class with fields to it and use it to populate fields in a .rdlc file.

However, in a ASP.NET web project (Alt+Shift+D) does not bring up a data source pane. So my question was how do I go about populating a report with fields from a class?